# Using a function inside a map on a map attribute

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a spring boot backend endpoint which takes a customer id and returns how many orders the customer has made. This is done with Spring boot PathVariable , so the endpoint looks like this :

[image]

```
"api/v1/totalorders/{id}"
```

The endpoint takes in the id in the url and returns the total orders as a number in the body as you see in the picture, it return 1 total order for customer with id 2.

I want to show this inside my table where the other customer information is shown, this is how the table looks now :

[image]

I want totalOrders to show the amount of orders by taking in the customer id in the same row and returning the amount of orders.

I use axios to get the API endpoint in my APIService like this :

```
const GET_TOTAL_ORDERS_API_URL ='http://localhost:8080/api/v1/totalorders/';
const authConfig = {
  auth: {
      username: "admin",
      password: "admin"
  }
}
     getTotalOrders(customerId) {
      return axios.get(GET_TOTAL_ORDERS_API_URL+customerId, authConfig)
  }
```

And then in my listCustomers class component,this is how the constructor looks :

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = { customers: [],totalOrders: []}
    this.onSort = this.onSort.bind(this)
}
```

My getTotalOrders looks like this :

```
   getTotalOrders(id) {

  APIService.getTotalOrders(id).then((response) => {
    this.setState({totalOrders: response.data})
})
}
```

EDIT : My render method :

```
 render(){
    return (
          <div className="listCustomersContainer"> 
          <NavLink to="/adminhomepage"><button id="backButton">Go back</button></NavLink>
        <br/>

        <div className="customerTableContainer">
            <table className="table table-bordered" id="customerTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr className="customerTableRow">

                        
                        <th onClick={e => this.onSort(e, 'customerId')}>Customer ID </th>
                        <th onClick={e => this.onSort(e, 'customerFirstName')}>Customer First-Name</th>
                        <th onClick={e => this.onSort(e, 'customerLastName')}>Customer Last-Name</th>
                        <th onClick={e => this.onSort(e, 'customerAdress')}>Customer Adress</th>
                        <th onClick={e => this.onSort(e, 'customerEmail')}>Customer E-mail</th>
                        <th onClick={e => this.onSort(e, 'totalOrders')}>Total Orders</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    {
                this.state.customers.map(
                        customer => {
                        {this.getTotalOrders(customer.customerId)}
                        return (
                        <tr className="customerTableRow" key= {customer.customerId} >
                            <td id="customerIdMap">{customer.customerId}</td>
                            <td>{customer.customerFirstName}</td>
                            <td>{customer.customerLastName}</td>
                            <td>{customer.customerAdress}</td>
                            <td>{customer.customerEmail}</td>
                            <td>{this.state.totalOrders}</td>
                        </tr>);
                    })
                            
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
            
            </div>
        </div>
        
    )
}
```

The totalOrders are now showing but are looping through and showing the same amount for both customers :

[image]

Stack trace for backend that shows that it keeps looping

```
    2021-12-27 11:15:26.412  INFO 13050 --- [io-8081-exec-10] LOGGER                                   : LISTED TOTAL ORDERS FOR A CUSTOMER
Hibernate: select count(*) from TBL_ORDER WHERE CUSTOMER_ID=?
2021-12-27 11:15:26.680  INFO 13050 --- [nio-8081-exec-8] LOGGER                                   : LISTED TOTAL ORDERS FOR A CUSTOMER
Hibernate: select count(*) from TBL_ORDER WHERE CUSTOMER_ID=?
2021-12-27 11:15:26.702  INFO 13050 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] LOGGER                                   : LISTED TOTAL ORDERS FOR A CUSTOMER
Hibernate: select count(*) from TBL_ORDER WHERE CUSTOMER_ID=?
2021-12-27 11:15:27.118  INFO 13050 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] LOGGER                                   : LISTED TOTAL ORDERS FOR A CUSTOMER
Hibernate: select count(*) from TBL_ORDER WHERE CUSTOMER_ID=?
2021-12-27 11:15:27.153  INFO 13050 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] LOGGER                                   : LISTED TOTAL ORDERS FOR A CUSTOMER
Hibernate: select count(*) from TBL_ORDER WHERE CUSTOMER_ID=?
2021-12-27 11:15:27.490  INFO 13050 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] LOGGER                                   : LISTED TOTAL ORDERS FOR A CUSTOMER
Hibernate: select count(*) from TBL_ORDER WHERE CUSTOMER_ID=?
2021-12-27 11:15:27.673  INFO 13050 --- [nio-8081-exec-6] LOGGER                                   : LISTED TOTAL ORDERS FOR A CUSTOMER
Hibernate: select count(*) from TBL_ORDER WHERE CUSTOMER_ID=?
2021-12-27 11:15:28.012  INFO 13050 --- [nio-8081-exec-5] LOGGER                                   : LISTED TOTAL ORDERS FOR A CUSTOMER
Hibernate: select count(*) from TBL_ORDER WHERE CUSTOMER_ID=?
2021-12-27 11:15:28.140  INFO 13050 --- [nio-8081-exec-7] LOGGER                                   : LISTED TOTAL ORDERS FOR A CUSTOMER
Hibernate: select count(*) from TBL_ORDER WHERE CUSTOMER_ID=?
2021-12-27 11:15:28.515  INFO 13050 --- [nio-8081-exec-9] LOGGER                                   : LISTED TOTAL ORDERS FOR A CUSTOMER
Hibernate: select count(*) from TBL_ORDER WHERE CUSTOMER_ID=?
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the state variable in the last cell of the table like below:

```
...
<td>{this.state.totalOrders}</td>
...
```

Also, when you get a response back from the API, you need to set the value of this state variable like so:

```
this.setState({totalOrders: response.data});
```

```
this.state.customers.map(
                            customer => {
                            {this.getTotalOrders(customer.customerId)}
                            return (
                            <tr className="customerTableRow" key= {customer.customerId} >
                                <td id="customerIdMap">{customer.customerId}</td>
                                <td>{customer.customerFirstName}</td>
                                <td>{customer.customerLastName}</td>
                                <td>{customer.customerAdress}</td>
                                <td>{customer.customerEmail}</td>
                                <td>{this.state.totalOrders}</td>
                            </tr>);
                        })
```

Comment: It doesn't return anything still, is this because I haven't called the function? Because the id in getTotalOrders(id) is just an empty variable where I want to pass customer.customerId

Comment: Updated the answer showing how you can invoke the getTotalOrders method as well.

Comment: Thank you, but the code after return is unreachable and nothing shows except the table head now. Do I need another return statement if I have one exaclty below the render() method? 

I edited my post to include my class constructor and my whole render method

Comment: Try removing the "return" from the map method...

Comment: I removed it, nothing shows still , I edited my post to include the whole render method

Comment: Updated answer and tested as well ... it should work now

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't show anything when I add the line after customer => , where the function is called on customer.customerId. 

If I remove it I can see the table contents again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240461/discussion-between-ruthless-and-siddharth-s).